# codeigniter view in construct

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

```
class Index extends MY_Controller {
     public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
     }
}

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('index');
        die();
    }
}
```

Why in this way the view is not rendering in browser?

Can I use something like this as a solution? Or there is another better way?

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->output->_display();
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you killing your constructor? It would be best if you explained what you actually wanted to achieve in the question

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `die()` after loading view, remove that line it will work.

Comment: If I remove it Hooks will run, which is not likely.

Comment: +1 Correct answer for me,but still, u need to mention how to stop the code from being executed.